# How do I show $ amount just once ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The project table

```
PID   ProjectName Phase PhaseName Price  
16-A  XYZ         1     Phase 1   $500
16-A  XYZ         2     Phase 2   $500
16-A  XYZ         3     Phase 3   $500
17-A  ZYX         1     Phase 1   $250
17-A  ZYX         2     Phase 2   $250
```

I want a desired output like below

```
PID   ProjectName Phase PhaseName Price  
16-A  XYZ         1     Phase 1   $500
16-A  XYZ         2     Phase 2   0
16-A  XYZ         3     Phase 3   0
17-A  ZYX         2     Phase 2   $250
17-A  ZYX         3     Phase 3   0
```

Like you see in the sample desired output in the table above, I want to show the $ for only once variation because essentially the cost of a PID is $500 but that PID has 3 variation names. So having $ multiple times for every variation will show extra amount in the cost report. 
What is the best way to filter this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the price is always the same and there is always a `Phase` 1, then:

```
select 
     PID
  ,  ProjectName
  ,  Phase
  ,  PhaseName
  ,  Price = case when Phase = 1 then Price else 0 end
from t
```

If there is not always a `Phase` 1, then we can get the `price` for the first instance of each `PID` using `row_number()` like so:

```
select 
     PID
  ,  ProjectName
  ,  Phase
  ,  PhaseName
  ,  Price = case when rn = 1 then Price else 0 end
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by PID
        order by Phase
        )
  from t
  ) as r
```

Comment: This worked for me only when I consider that there always be Phase 1 for every PID but here the PID can have Phase 3 or Phase 2,3 or Phase 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
    select 
         PID
        ,ProjectName
        ,Phase
        ,PhaseName
        ,case when (lag(Price,1) over (partition by PID order by Phase)) = Price 
             then 0 else Price end as Price
    from project
```

It's that simple.  You end up with...

[image]

Comment: you should probably change that to `partition by PID order by Phase`. If two projects have the same price, your code zeroes out the new project's price too. http://rextester.com/SSREC47137